# ALAMOFIRE post request image download and binding in a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Helo i am new to ios developing please guide me i have created a alamofire post request with parameter i dont have any problem in that . After that i need to download the image url from the Json response generated, i dont know how to download the image url from json and keep that in a array , after that have to download the inage from the url need to bind it in a image view of collection view . 
I dont have any idea about how to take the image url from the json response then keep that in a array , then have to download the image bind it in a collection view. 
Please help me

I have updated the api class which I have written in my project, it was fetching the data properly from the url and I don't know how to parse it into collection view cell image

```
 func apiclass(){

    if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authToken") == nil){
        self.httpObj.getAuthToken()
    }
    else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authExpireDate") != nil && Date().compare((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authExpireDate") as? Date)!) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending){
        globalConstants.prefs.setValue(nil, forKey: "authToken")
        self.httpObj.getAuthToken()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authToken") != nil){
            var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: globalConstants.tokenUrl as URL)
            let authToken:String = (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authToken") as? String)!
            request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: globalConstants.tokenUrl as URL)
            request.addValue("Bearer \(authToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.addValue(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Device-ID")
            request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "UUID") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Unique-ID")
            request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "countryCode") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Country-Code")
            request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "currencyCode") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Currency-Code")
            request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "currencySymbol") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Currency-Symbol")
            request.addValue(String(stringInterpolationSegment: (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "currencyFactor"))!), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Currency-Factor")
            request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "appSource") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-App-Source")
            request.addValue(globalConstants.appVersion, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-App-Version")
            request.addValue(String(stringInterpolationSegment: (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? Int)!), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EStore-ID")

            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userEmail") != nil){
                request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userEmail") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Email")
            }
            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userId") != nil){
                request.addValue(String(stringInterpolationSegment: (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userId"))!), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-User-ID")
            }

            print(self.apiRequestParameters)

            var requestParameters:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            requestParameters = [

                "mode" : "design",
                "productGroup" : 0

            ]

            print(requestParameters)

            request.url = globalConstants.ESDCUrl as URL

            self.httpObj.sendRequest("POST", requestDict: requestParameters, request: request as URLRequest, completion: { (result, error) in
                print(result!)



                if(error == nil){

                    // move to shopping cart


                  //  dictResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary

                    self.dictResult = result as! NSArray

                    self.categorycollectionview.reloadData()




                    //self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

//                        let requestDataDict:NSDictionary = incomingRequetArray[0] as! NSDictionary
//                        let newDict: NSURL = requestDataDict.object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? NSDictionary
//

```
                }
                else{
                    let alert = UIAlertView()
                    alert.isHidden = true
                    alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
                    alert.message = globalConstants.apiErrorMessage
                    alert.show()
                }
            })
        }
    })

}
```

I have updated the json response for my post request. please give me a solution. I can get the below response in console.

```
(   {
    ActualPrice = 0;
    AssuredTitle = "<null>";
    CashBackAmount = 0;
    CashBackDiscountPercentage = 0;
    Code = "";
    Cost = "<null>";
    CreateDate = "<null>";
    CustomSize = 0;
    Delivery = "<null>";
    DeliveryDate = "<null>";
    DeliveryDays = "<null>";
    Designer = "<null>";
    Discount = "<null>";
    DiscountCost = "<null>";
    DispatchDateDisplay = "<null>";
    Exclusive = "<null>";
    Gender = "<null>";
    HasReadyMadeColor = 0;
    HasReadyMadeSizes = 0;
    ID = 41;
    ImageUrl = "https://images.cbazaar.com/images/aqua-blue-georgette-abaya-isbs1805991-u.jpg";
    Is7DD = "<null>";
    IsCustomizable = 0;
    IsExclusive = 0;
    IsFree = "<null>";
    IsFreeShipping = 0;
    IsInWishlist = 0;
    IsLookUp = 0;
    IsNew = 0;
    IsProductAnimation = 0;
    IsReadyToShip = 0;
    LargeImageUrl = "<null>";
    ListingImage = "<null>";
    LowerLargeImage = "<null>";
    LowerThumbImage = "<null>";
    MoneyFactor = "<null>";
    MoneyOffFactor = "<null>";
    Name = "Islamic wear";
    OfferImageUrl = "<null>";
    OldPrice = 0;
    OutOfStock = 0;
    PDUrl = "<null>";
    ProductBigLink = "<null>";
    ProductCollectionReference = "<null>";
    ProductHisImage = "<null>";
    ProductSaleCycle = 0;
    ProductType = 168;
    ProductV2VRatio = 0;
    PromotionTypeID = "<null>";
    Promotions = "<null>";
    PromotionsIcon = "<null>";
    Rating = "<null>";
    SalePrice = "<null>";
    ShowOldPrice = 0;
    SizeChart = "<null>";
    SuperClassification = "<null>";
    TypeGroup = "<null>";
    TypeShortCode = "<null>";
    UpperLargeImage = "<null>";
    UpperThumbImage = "<null>";
    VendorType = "<null>";
    VisitCount = 0;
})
```

Comment: if you can provide the json responce of your post request then i can help you out

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: are you using `AlamofireImage` for download the image or else

Comment: @Ajay saini i have posted my son response please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class dataModel{
let profImage: String?
let name: String?
init(profImg: String,name: String)
self.profImage = profImg
self.name = name
}
```

In the CollectionViewController

```
let arrayModel = [dataModel]()

After you got the image url add data to array

let dataAll = (dataModel[profImg: YourImageVariable, name: yourNameVariable])
arrayModel.append(dataAll)



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCellname", for: indexPath) as? yourCell {
   let dataIndex = dataModel[indexPath.row]
              cell.updateUI(setMdata: dataIndex)
            return cell


    }

    }
```

In the cell class import SDWebImage

```
class myCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profImage: UIImageView!
func updateUI(setMdata: dataModel) {
name.text = dataModel.name
profImagesd._setImage(with: URL(string:dataModel.profImg), placeholderImage: nill)

}
}
```